# Into which file system should I format my flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, filesystems, ntfs, fat32

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-platform filesystem](https://superuser.com/questions/45130/cross-platform-filesystem)

I want to reformat a my 2 Gb flash drive for cross-platform compatibility, but I don't know the difference between all the file systems. I know that FAT32 is compatible with Windows and Linux, but I believe NTFS is, as well.

- Which file system has the widest compatibility?
- Which file system is least likely to damage my files if the drive is removed unsafely?
- If I want to secure my drive with a password, must I use a specific file system?

My knowledge of file systems is sorely lacking; I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: this question has been asked a few times before.  best duplicate may be: http://superuser.com/questions/45130/cross-platform-filesystem .. others: http://superuser.com/questions/72546/external-hard-drive-how-to-format-it http://superuser.com/questions/12102/what-filesystem-to-have-on-my-usb-harddrive-fat32-or-ntfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with FAT32. If there was a need for large files, maybe I would opt for something else. But on a 2 Gb USB, there is really no problems in that view. Pretty much everything can read from it, and write to it, it being a rather old nowadays system.

I've never experienced any loss of files, but if you really wish to be sure just safely remove/unmount regularly. File corruption is not so much related to the filesystem itself, but rather to the operations pending in the moment of the forced removal (so to speak).

Comment: +1 FAT32 is just fine, the 4GB file size limit doesn't matter on a 2GB stick :)

Comment: Doesn't NTFS have some certain flags, though? As I remember, one time my NTFS external didn't get removed safely in Windows and when I tried to mount it in Ubuntu I had to force it with `mount` (and some parameter)—it wouldn't mount automatically or manually via GNOME, I think; some NTFS flag hadn't been set correctly since it wasn't removed safely.

Comment: @Nathaniel - Could be ... I haven't had any problems with the above, but I'm not disregarding anything. It's just that I haven't encountered it.