# migrating files and shortcuts from old XP to NEW 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, migration

I have a company who has got a new Windows 7 PC. Any recommendations on how to migrate all of the files over and also how to I bring the IE and Chrome shortcuts and setting over/

Are there any issues I should foresee when copying from a real old xp machine to new 64b windows 7 machine?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&amp;A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. Questions here should try to follow the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq), and be able to be answered in a clear, concise manner. In order to do so, you should post questions that can be answered by experts, show research effort, and have as much detail as possible.

Comment: I disagre Oliver. 1.How to migrate the files.
2. How to migrate ie and chrome set up.
3. What issues to expect.
If we cannot ask questions which may receive a wrong answer or incite debate then there never would bea question asked. In that world no-one would learn.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checklist for migrating old Windows to Windows 7, making a fresh install](http://superuser.com/questions/58930/checklist-for-migrating-old-windows-to-windows-7-making-a-fresh-install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues in transferring files between machines with different OSes; file paths are different, many apps install only files needed by the installed OS so moving it to a machine with another OS will break it. Some files, such as application config and installers, are hidden but can be migrated to new machines. Other files, such as application caches and registry settings, are machine or user specific and cannot be migrated, and it is not obvious which are which. Do not try to copy files manually.

The [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) app will migrate user data and documents. The Windows [User State Migration Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/migrating-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7.aspx) can migrate some application settings to a new machine.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome support [bookmark setting sync'ing](http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1281195), so just setup the sync in chrome on the old computer... and open chrome on the new computer and turn the sync'ing on there too. Everything should be copied over for you.

You might want to export the IE bookmarks/cookies into chrome first. And set it up before the sync